# Conditional merging with many variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am wondering if there was a faster, more elegant data.table solution to my following question.

Suppose we have two datasets

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(income = runif(10, 0,1),
                  ID = 1:10)
DT2 <- data.table(height = runif(20,0,1),
                  weight = runif(20,0,1),
                  V1 = runif(20,0,1),
                  V2 = runif(20,0,2),
                  type = rep(c("Parents", "Children"),10))
DT2 <- DT2[order(type)][, ID := rep(1:10,2)]
```

The first dataset is a "household" level dataset with household identifiers given by ID, from 1:10.

There is a second dataset, `DT2` which has four variables for each parent and child, for each household ID. What I want to do is merge all the variables (height, weight, V1, V2) of the Parents and Children in each row/observation of DT1. So we would have eight variables to merge, four for the parents and four for the children.

To do so, I can simply write the following:

```
DT1[DT2[type == "Parents"], c("height_parents", "weight_parents",
                              "V1_parents", "V2_parents") := list(i.height, i.weight,
                                                                  i.V1, i.V2), on = c(ID = "ID")]
DT1[DT2[type == "Children"], c("height_children", "weight_children",
                               "V1_children", "V2_children") := list(i.height, i.weight,
                                                                     i.V1, i.V2), on = c(ID = "ID")]
```

The output looks like:

```
 income ID height_parents weight_parents V1_parents V2_parents height_children
1: 0.70647001  1     0.49163534    0.164385214  0.6806198 1.72937701      0.04655907
2: 0.07658058  2     0.06776809    0.234182275  0.4456820 1.76814822      0.45665042
3: 0.49770601  3     0.23255515    0.709256017  0.3514867 1.83387012      0.24395311
4: 0.51944306  4     0.30555999    0.974742471  0.0529102 0.06094086      0.22356168
5: 0.23075737  5     0.51104028    0.007269433  0.4157508 1.00207079      0.98915308
6: 0.86449990  6     0.75420198    0.211342425  0.9837331 0.03520897      0.86080818
   weight_children V1_children V2_Children
1:       0.3398447   0.7454582   0.6761706
2:       0.8475106   0.4716267   1.5231691
3:       0.8895790   0.1561395   1.8721056
4:       0.3503219   0.2663775   0.2408758
5:       0.3902352   0.9332958   1.3532260
6:       0.7648748   0.6969372   1.3289579
```

Note that if I had many different "types" (here there is only two) and/or many different variables to merge (here there is only 4), the above would get quickly laborious and verbose. The dataset I am using has many different variables and types. Thus, I am looking to do this in a more efficient way. In particular, I want to be able to define a vector:

```
merge_variables = c("height", "weight", "V1", "V2")
```

and in a data.table fashion, have all of these variables merge for both parents and children. I want the new variables to have an underscore in them with the types name (e.g.`height_parents` and `height_children`).

I hope I've communicated my request clearly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `mget` to do this i.e. create object names as string with `paste`, then do a join `on` the 'ID' after subsetting the 'DT2' and assign the output of the columns (i.e. `mget` returns a `list` of vectors) to create new columns in 'DT1'

```
merge_variables = c("height", "weight", "V1", "V2") 
parent_nm <- paste0(merge_variables, "_parents")
child_nm <- paste0(merge_variables, "_children")

DT1[DT2[type == "Parents"], (parent_nm) := mget(paste0("i.", merge_variables)), on = .(ID)]
DT1[DT2[type == "Children"], (child_nm) := mget(paste0("i.", merge_variables)), on = .(ID)]
```

-output

```
> DT1
        income ID height_parents weight_parents V1_parents V2_parents height_children weight_children V1_children V2_children
 1: 0.26550866  1     0.20597457      0.4820801 0.47761962  0.6781459       0.1765568       0.5995658  0.86120948   1.6788807
 2: 0.37212390  2     0.68702285      0.4935413 0.43809711  0.6933670       0.3841037       0.1862176  0.24479728   0.6675499
 3: 0.57285336  3     0.76984142      0.8273733 0.07067905  0.9527025       0.4976992       0.6684667  0.09946616   1.7843967
 4: 0.90820779  4     0.71761851      0.7942399 0.31627171  1.7286789       0.9919061       0.1079436  0.51863426   0.7799791
 5: 0.20168193  5     0.38003518      0.7237109 0.66200508  1.5546414       0.7774452       0.4112744  0.40683019   1.9212360
 6: 0.89838968  6     0.93470523      0.8209463 0.91287592  0.8693190       0.2121425       0.6470602  0.29360337   1.4250294
 7: 0.94467527  7     0.65167377      0.7829328 0.45906573  0.7999887       0.1255551       0.5530363  0.33239467   0.6507043
 8: 0.66079779  8     0.26722067      0.5297196 0.65087047  1.5141743       0.3861141       0.7893562  0.25801678   0.4053845
 9: 0.62911404  9     0.01339033      0.0233312 0.47854525  1.4222424       0.3823880       0.4772301  0.76631067   0.2433838
10: 0.06178627 10     0.86969085      0.7323137 0.08424691  0.4909770       0.3403490       0.6927316  0.87532133   0.2866088
```

---

Or another option is to `dcast` the 'DT2' to 'wide' format and do a join (But, here we are not assigning (`:=`), thus it wouldn't update the original DT1)

```
DT1[dcast(DT2, ID ~ type, value.var = merge_variables), on = .(ID)]
        income ID height_Children height_Parents weight_Children weight_Parents V1_Children V1_Parents V2_Children V2_Parents
 1: 0.26550866  1       0.1765568     0.20597457       0.5995658      0.4820801  0.86120948 0.47761962   1.6788807  0.6781459
 2: 0.37212390  2       0.3841037     0.68702285       0.1862176      0.4935413  0.24479728 0.43809711   0.6675499  0.6933670
 3: 0.57285336  3       0.4976992     0.76984142       0.6684667      0.8273733  0.09946616 0.07067905   1.7843967  0.9527025
 4: 0.90820779  4       0.9919061     0.71761851       0.1079436      0.7942399  0.51863426 0.31627171   0.7799791  1.7286789
 5: 0.20168193  5       0.7774452     0.38003518       0.4112744      0.7237109  0.40683019 0.66200508   1.9212360  1.5546414
 6: 0.89838968  6       0.2121425     0.93470523       0.6470602      0.8209463  0.29360337 0.91287592   1.4250294  0.8693190
 7: 0.94467527  7       0.1255551     0.65167377       0.5530363      0.7829328  0.33239467 0.45906573   0.6507043  0.7999887
 8: 0.66079779  8       0.3861141     0.26722067       0.7893562      0.5297196  0.25801678 0.65087047   0.4053845  1.5141743
 9: 0.62911404  9       0.3823880     0.01339033       0.4772301      0.0233312  0.76631067 0.47854525   0.2433838  1.4222424
10: 0.06178627 10       0.3403490     0.86969085       0.6927316      0.7323137  0.87532133 0.08424691   0.2866088  0.4909770
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This works. But I am wondering if there was a way that I can get the variables to "update" as well. It seems that `mget` will add the variables, but not "update" them.

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous The `:=` will do the update on DT1

Comment: When I add the following code `DT1 <- DT1 %>%
  .[, c("height", "weight") := 0]` and then merge as you suggested, the columns for height and weight are still 0.

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous you are using `dplyr` methods whereas I used `data.table` methods to update.  The dplyr methods are different and it wouldn't work as you wanted because the `:=` work in a different way in dplyr

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous I added another option as well i.e. with `dcast` to simplify your steps

Comment: The `dcast` way works, but I am hoping to do it via merging. When I apply your code after running ```DT1 <- data.table(income = runif(10, 0,1), ID = 1:10)
DT1[, c("height", "weight") := 0]

DT2 <- data.table(height = runif(20,0,1),
                  weight = runif(20,0,1),
                  V1 = runif(20,0,1),
                  V2 = runif(20,0,2),
                  type = rep(c("Parents", "Children"),10))
DT2 <- DT2[order(type)][, ID := rep(1:10,2)]``` I am still getting zeros for weight and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238070/discussion-between-plausibly-exogenous-and-akrun).